# in ThreeJs's instancedMesh, is there any way to add/remove instance?

Tags: javascript, 3d, threejs-editor

I'm considering this problem for several days. still, I have no a beautiful answer.

How can i delete an instance between 0 and the `limit`? Someone recommended using `updateRange`. but, i still need move numbers' indices in the matrix.

That moving the indices and then using `updateRange` is a solution.

Is there a nice one?